How to compare date from Firestore timestamp to current date in Flutter?
I need to make a query to summarize all the money spent during the last day.
The documents have a field with a price which I want to summarize and the field with a timestamp.
Firestore stores timestamps in this format: June 12, 2024, at 6:27:01 PM UTC+3, but I don't really need all of this data. I just want to make a comparison to make sure that the current day and day of the timestamp are the same, and I don't understand how to do it cleanly and efficiently.
I tried to convert the timestamp value to match the format of Flutter when adding data to Firestore. The query to add data to Firestore looked like this:
Future<void> addGood(
      String good, client, int amount, double price, String username) {
    return goods.add({
      'good': good,
      'amount': amount,
      'price': price,
      'client': client,
      'username': currentUser!.email,
      'timestampday': Timestamp.now().toDate().toString()
    });
  }

Then I changed the way this collection stores timestamps to string format. Probably it could help somehow, but I don't know how to work with this data after converting it.

What's your question?  It's not clear.  "I don't know how to work with this data" isn't telling us very much.  Consider just storing the specific information that you need, and don't try to format anything as strings, since they don't do well for comparisons that must be numeric in nature.  Your job will be a lot easier if you just store what you need.

"Firestore stores timestamps in this format: June 12, 2024 at 6:27:01 PM UTC+3" No, it does not store timestamps as formatted strings.


Firestore stores timestamps in this format: June 12, 2024, at 6:27:01 PM UTC+3, but I don't really need all of this data.

A Firestore Timestamp, contains by design the date and time with a microseconds precision. There is no way you can store a Timestamp field with partial data, for example, only the day. If you need to only have a field that stores the day, then you should consider creating a field of type string called day, and store the name of the day separately.
If you don't want to have an additional field, to only have the day, you can then call toDate() on a Timestamp object. The type of object that is returned is DateTime. As you can see, this class contains a field called day. Now, you can compare the day in the Firestore Timestamp with any other day you want.

I remade the document structure to store day, month and year separately and now it works perfectly fine. Thank you for clarifications on how Timestamps work.

You're very welcome, @1rre7!

Hey @1rre7. Can I help you with other information?
